# installation phpmyadmin-error:The mbstring extension is missing. In my php.ini mbstring is active(semi-colon is removed)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I don't manage installation phpmyadmin-4.4.12-all-languages. If I write in my browser http://localhost/phpmyadmin44/, it appears: phpmyadmin - error. The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. In my file php.ini,  mbstring extension is active(semi-colon is removed). In my computer is working Apache24,PHP56,MySQL56.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if php.ini contains a reference to the mbstring extension, it does not mean that the file is present in your extension directory. You have to install a package containing this extension. If your server is on Linux, the package may be called php5-mbstring.

Comment: I have server on Windows 8.1. Extension  directory has following path: c:/web/php56/ext/php_mbstring.dll.Thank you

Comment: If you are the one who removed the semi-colon in php.ini, did you restart Apache after? Also, if you're talking about the extension_dir directive in php.ini, it should contain a directory name, not a complete path that includes the filename.

Comment: I restarted Apache. Path from php56 - c:/web/php56/ext/php_mbstring.dll. File php.ini - extension_dir = "c:/web/php56/ext". Thank you.

Comment: If you place a script (let's call it test.php) in your document root, containing <?php phpinfo(); ?> and if you visit your website's test.php, do you see a mention of mbstring in the list of extensions? You can compare by visiting http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/?pma_username=root and clicking on "Show PHP information".

Comment: my php phpinfo-php566-php extension(column):20131226,php extension build(column):API20131226,TS,VC11. DEMO php569-0+deb8u1-php extension(column):20131226, php extension build(column):API20131226, NTS. Thank you.

Comment: What I mean is that on the phpinfo output, there is a section with a "mbstring" header, containing lines such as "multibyte support" equals "enabled". Do you see the same section on your server?

Comment: I didn't find in php phpinfo() anything similar as a section with a "mbstring" header with lines "multibyte support" equals "enabled". Thank you.

Comment: So this means that your PHP installation does not have this extension. Is php_mbstring.dll really present in your c:/web/php56/ext directory.

Comment: The file php_mbstring.dll is really in installed php56. It directory is c:/web/php56/ext/php_mbstring.dll. In order it is between files php_ldap.dll and php_mysql.dll. Ican't open it. When I open it by programme PSPad editor there are only obscure numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Please show me the line in your php.ini that mentions mbstring. Also, did you try installing xampp from xampp.org? Usually this works well and gives you all the correct extensions.

Comment: php56, file php.ini - line 888 extension=php_mbstring.dll  Thank you

Comment: I installed XAMPP in my computer, but it dosn't work because ports 80, 3306 are occupied. Perhaps I would have to uninstalled Apache24, php56 and MySQL.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Comment: @universe2004
Please accept the answer about XAMPP below.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to install a complete and tested kit like XAMPP (see http://xampp.org).